# How can I block any new processes from running in ring 0

Tags: windows, powershell, kernel, regedit

Is there an app or a tool that will block anything non-windows running in ring 0 even if it has admin permissions

Comment: Sounds like you want a Code Integrity policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/device-guard/introduction-to-device-guard-virtualization-based-security-and-windows-defender-application-control

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen You should mention that physical access to the box lets you defeat that.

Comment: @TwistedNight? Why? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386992), and you probably need to rethink your security model.